# How to prevent a line from being consumed while iterating through a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a very simple task to achieve :

> **1)** Read an input csv file (that has a header section, with various
> length), **2)** Do some basic transformations on it (as a dataframe) and
> **3)** Make it as a new csv (including the same header section as the input csv).

My code below works fine except one annoying thing : the columns names are ignored while writing the new csv.

```
import pandas as pd

with open('input_file.csv', 'r') as f1, open('output_file.csv', 'w') as f2:

    extra = False
    for line in f1:
      if ',' not in line:
          extra = True
          f2.write(line)
      elif extra:
        break

    df = pd.read_csv(f1)

    # some basic processing here to df like below
    df.iat[0, 1] = 0 

    df.to_csv(f2, index=False)
```

My actual new csv looks like below (see how the line `col1,col2,col3` is missing) :

```
Title=foo
Date=16/08/2023
Category=bar
...
id1,0,2
id2,3,4
id3,5,6
```

Can you explain why, please ? I feel like it has to do with my loop (hence, the title of my question).

This is my input csv btw :

```
Title=foo
Date=16/08/2023
Category=bar
...
col1,col2,col3
id1,1,2
id2,3,4
id3,5,6
```

Comment: You are right, the line is consumed to recognize if it has a `,`. You can use the `tell` and `seek` methods of file objects to store and finally restore the file pointer position before calling `read_csv`.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but just so you know, the whole `with open('file.csv', 'r')` thing is unnecessary. Normally it would be good practise in Python, but pandas does lots of fancy file buffer reading/writing behind the scenes and safely manages the files. So basically if you completely forgo `with open()` it's still safe and good practise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you reuse `line`?

```
import pandas as pd
with open('input_file.csv', 'r') as f1, open('output_file.csv', 'w') as f2:
    extra = False
    for line in f1:
      if ',' not in line:
          extra = True
          f2.write(line)
      elif extra:
        break
    df = pd.read_csv(f1, names=line.strip().split(','))
    # some basic processing here to df like below
    df.iat[0, 1] = 0 
    df.to_csv(f2, index=False)
```

Alternatively, move back to the position before the line:

```
import pandas as pd
with open('input_file.csv', 'r') as f1, open('output_file.csv', 'w') as f2:
    extra = False
    pos = 0
    for line in f1:
      if ',' not in line:
          extra = True
          f2.write(line)
          pos = f2.tell()
      elif extra:
        f1.seek(pos)
        break
    df = pd.read_csv(f1)
    # some basic processing here to df like below
    df.iat[0, 1] = 0 
    df.to_csv(f2, index=False)
```

Output `df`:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0  id1     0     2
1  id2     3     4
2  id3     5     6
```

Comment: I'm so impressed. In hours, it never came to my mind that this `line` is remembered.  Thank you so much!

Comment: If `line` has a weird format with quotes, you might want to process it with the `csv` module rather than `split`

Comment: Yes, I have no control on the columns names, they can be anything. I'll be more than happy if you can show me how to process it with the `csv` module.

Comment: @rendezvous I'll have to check the exact syntax and will update later. In the meantime I provided another approch to go back to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Just rearrange/reduce the crucial loop to capture the line with column names:

```
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line)
    if ',' in line:
        break
```

Comment: Depending on what processing you do, this might not be a good idea as the output header might no longer be aligned

Comment: @mozway what doess mean "might no longer be aligned " in that simple context?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, sorry, I tested your solution and it has the same side effect as mine.

Comment: @Roman OP seems to want to process things before import and export. If columns change this won't work. For the simple example I agree this should work.